# Programmatically set pattern lock in Android

Tags: android, locking

I was able to set the password lock programmatically by using the below code but how can I set the pattern lock programmatically ?

```
mDevicePolicyManager.setPasswordQuality(mComponentName,DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING);
mDevicePolicyManager.setPasswordMinimumLength(mComponentName, 5);
boolean result = mDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword("a123456",  DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
```

Any help will be appreciated :) Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

This is your preferred flag:

```
private static final int REQ_CREATE_PATTERN = 1;

Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN,
                           null, your-context, LockPatternActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CREATE_PATTERN);
```

[See more](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/wiki/QuickUse)